# Ignoring 'ln' errors in Vagrant provisioning

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ln

I'm using a shell script in my Vagrantfile to create a symlink for Node.js (in a Ubuntu VM):

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

That works fine when I call `vagrant up` for the first time, but when I call `vagrant up --provision` after that (i.e., when the symlink already exists), I get the following error:

```
==> default: ln: 
==> default: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/node’: File exists
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

**How can I make Vagrant ignore the error raised by `ln`?** I have already tried to redirect its output to `/dev/null`, but that results in the same error:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node 2>/dev/null || true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-f` parameter:

```
ln -s -f /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

See [`ln` - Linux Command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ln.htm).